# Show filters from category & products, show filters relevant filter post selection (and non-relevant from active parent) & product count per filter

Tags: mysql, sql

I posted a similar question on 10 Jan 2020 ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59685243/sql-query-to-return-filters-applicable-to-products-contained-in-category-and-fil)) but my problem/question has expanded since then and don't want S.O. police on my back ;)

This is the criteria:

- There are filter categories and there are filters belong to those categories.
- Each filter displays a count of how many products belong to a filter.
- The number of available filters need to reduce depending on active filter selection to not only those that still apply to the pool of products but those that are also relevant to child filters of other filter categories.
- There is a caveat to the above, if only one filter category has child filters selected then all the sibling filters (filters of the same filter category are to still display) until a filter from another filter category is made active.  Once a filter from another filter category/parent is selected the previous full list can reduce but previously select filters must remain active just show a count of zero if that's the case.

I think I'm really close with the SQL below but it will not correctly update the count of products belonging to each filter upon selection.  The only way I can get it to work is if I change the OR to an AND in the SQL below but this then will not show the other child filters belonging to a filter category that has an active child filter.

I have provided schema and sample data here, along with a fiddle of samehttp://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/afbd4d7/1/0:

```
CREATE TABLE `store_categories` (
  `categories_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`categories_id`),
  KEY `idx_categories_parent_id` (`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `store_products` (
  `products_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `products_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`products_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `store_products_filters` (
  `pf_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pf_name` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `pf_sort` int(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `pf_to_pfc_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pf_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `store_products_filters_categories` (
  `pfc_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pfc_name` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `pfc_sort` int(4) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pfc_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `store_products_filters_to_products` (
  `pftp_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pftp_pf_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pftp_products_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pftp_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `store_products_to_categories` (
  `products_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `categories_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`products_id`,`categories_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `store_categories` VALUES ('1', '0');
INSERT INTO `store_categories` VALUES ('2', '1');
INSERT INTO `store_categories` VALUES ('3', '0');
INSERT INTO `store_categories` VALUES ('4', '1');
INSERT INTO `store_categories` VALUES ('5', '0');
INSERT INTO `store_categories` VALUES ('6', '0');
INSERT INTO `store_products` VALUES ('1', '1');
INSERT INTO `store_products` VALUES ('2', '1');
INSERT INTO `store_products` VALUES ('3', '1');
INSERT INTO `store_products` VALUES ('4', '1');
INSERT INTO `store_products` VALUES ('5', '0');
INSERT INTO `store_products_filters` VALUES ('1', 'Small', '0', '1');
INSERT INTO `store_products_filters` VALUES ('2', 'Medium', '0', '1');
INSERT INTO `store_products_filters` VALUES ('3', 'Large', '0', '1');
INSERT INTO `store_products_filters` VALUES ('4', 'Extra Large', '0', '1');
INSERT INTO `store_products_filters` VALUES ('5', 'Circle', '0', '2');
INSERT INTO `store_products_filters` VALUES ('6', 'Square', '0', '2');
INSERT INTO `store_products_filters` VALUES ('7', 'Triangle', '0', '2');
INSERT INTO `store_products_filters` VALUES ('8', 'Red', '5000', '3');
INSERT INTO `store_products_filters` VALUES ('9', 'Blue', '5000', '3');
INSERT INTO `store_products_filters` VALUES ('10', 'Black', '2000', '3');
INSERT INTO `store_products_filters` VALUES ('11', 'Yellow', '5000', '3');
INSERT INTO `store_products_filters_categories` VALUES ('1', 'Size', '300');
INSERT INTO `store_products_filters_categories` VALUES ('2', 'Type', '100');
INSERT INTO `store_products_filters_categories` VALUES ('3', 'Colour', '400');
INSERT INTO `store_products_filters_to_products` VALUES ('1', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `store_products_filters_to_products` VALUES ('2', '6', '1');
INSERT INTO `store_products_filters_to_products` VALUES ('3', '9', '1');
INSERT INTO `store_products_filters_to_products` VALUES ('4', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `store_products_filters_to_products` VALUES ('5', '5', '2');
INSERT INTO `store_products_filters_to_products` VALUES ('6', '8', '2');
INSERT INTO `store_products_filters_to_products` VALUES ('7', '2', '3');
INSERT INTO `store_products_filters_to_products` VALUES ('8', '7', '3');
INSERT INTO `store_products_filters_to_products` VALUES ('9', '11', '3');
INSERT INTO `store_products_filters_to_products` VALUES ('10', '3', '4');
INSERT INTO `store_products_filters_to_products` VALUES ('11', '5', '4');
INSERT INTO `store_products_filters_to_products` VALUES ('12', '10', '4');
INSERT INTO `store_products_to_categories` VALUES ('1', '2');
INSERT INTO `store_products_to_categories` VALUES ('2', '2');
INSERT INTO `store_products_to_categories` VALUES ('3', '2');
INSERT INTO `store_products_to_categories` VALUES ('4', '2');
INSERT INTO `store_products_to_categories` VALUES ('5', '2');
```

There are 3 active filters, Small, Medium and Circle.
There are 2 "Small" sized products
There is 1 "Medium" sized product
There are 2 products that have a "Circle" filter applied to them but only one of those is "Small" and the other is "Large"

With Small, Medium filters applied I would expect/like Circle to show 1 but it shows a count of 2

```
OR pf.pf_id IN (
        SELECT
            pf_id
        FROM
            store_products_filters
        WHERE
            pf_to_pfc_id IN (1, 2)
    )
```

My thought so far is to remove the above SQL if filters from more than one filter category are active.

You can see an example of what I'm trying to achieve on this site https://www.ukpos.com/display-stands-frames-and-noticeboards which is powered by Magento.  I'm not sure if the filters are out of the box or a added plugin.

My full SQL below.

```
SELECT
    pfc.pfc_id,
    pfc.pfc_name,
    pf.pf_id,
    pf.pf_name,
    count(pftp.pftp_pf_id) AS products_in_filter
FROM
    store_products_filters_to_products pftp
LEFT JOIN store_products_filters pf ON pftp.pftp_pf_id = pf.pf_id
LEFT JOIN store_products_filters_categories pfc ON pf.pf_to_pfc_id = pfc_id
WHERE
    pftp_products_id IN (
        SELECT
            ptc.products_id
        FROM
            store_products_to_categories ptc
        LEFT JOIN store_products p ON ptc.products_id = p.products_id
        WHERE
            p.products_status = 1
        AND (
            ptc.categories_id = 1
            OR ptc.categories_id IN (
                SELECT
                    categories_id
                FROM
                    store_categories
                WHERE
                    parent_id = '1'
            )
        )
    )
AND (
    pf.pf_id IN (
        SELECT
            pftp_pf_id
        FROM
            store_products_filters_categories
        WHERE
            pftp_products_id IN (
                SELECT
                    pftp.pftp_products_id
                FROM
                    store_products_filters_to_products pftp
                JOIN store_products_filters pf ON pf.pf_id = pftp.pftp_pf_id
                GROUP BY
                    pftp.pftp_products_id
                HAVING
                    (
                        sum(pf.pf_id = 1) > 0
                        OR sum(pf.pf_id = 2) > 0
                    )
                AND (sum(pf.pf_id = 5) > 0)
            )
    )
    OR pf.pf_id IN (
        SELECT
            pf_id
        FROM
            store_products_filters
        WHERE
            pf_to_pfc_id IN (1, 2)
    )
)
GROUP BY
    pfc.pfc_id,
    pftp.pftp_pf_id
ORDER BY
    pfc.pfc_sort ASC,
    pfc.pfc_name ASC,
    pf.pf_sort ASC,
    pf.pf_name ASC
```

Comment: In reality, approximately how many products and filters are there likely to be?

Comment: For instance, the linked site has 96 products under 'display stands frames and noticeboards'. Well, I wouldn't bother executing separate queries to filter on such a tiny dataset. Instead, I'd return the entire dataset to a json array, and then use a bit of javascript to filter.

Comment: Also, a couple of things to note: In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate. And `LEFT JOIN p... WHERE p =...` resolves itself as `INNER JOIN  p...`.

Comment: @Strawberry the amount of products is irrelevant when it's part of client spec.

The project is near completion now and I would rather fix what is there than to start from scratch again.

Comment: @Strawberry regarding "absence of aggregating functions, a GROUP BY..." is there somewhere I can read more about this/see examples, would be great to know more.

Comment: Well, there's the manual

Comment: If by 'client', you mean someone who intends to own and run an online shopping website, then I'm sure they neither know nor care how or where the filtering occurs, just that the UX is satisfactory.

Comment: @Strawberry client as in the customer who has paid for this exact functionality. As mentioned I am not starting from scratch on this, so I'd quite like to get past "client" and completely different alternative routes and concentrate on the question I've asked which we seem to be moving away from.

Comment: From the point of view of the end user, the functionality is exactly the same. The only difference is that your method requires a round trip to the database each time - which is slower. I haven't looked 'under-the-hood' but I suspect that the linked site works in exactly the way you suggest, which would explain the notable pause every time you select or deselect a filter. Anyway, clearly you want to do it that way, which is fine - if no one else chimes in, I'll try to offer up some pointers for both methods. Unfortunately, I'm really busy for the next few days.

Comment: @Strawberry I'd appreciate it, thank you.  In terms of the alternative solution it depends on how complete it is, at this stage because the existing is almost complete albeit the query it would be good to try and salvage that.  If the alternative is comprehensive enough then I could be tempted to swap it out.

Comment: @Ian Stanley, thanks for the edit.  The SQL is correct on the fiddle which is where the sample data and schema is/was but the posted SQL in the question here was from the working project.  It wasn't an issue until the sample data/schema was posted/merged in the question here also, so well spotted.